# How to determine where does `\input{}` search for a file?

Tags: miktex, input

I have some file `foo-<YYYY>.tex` which I update every year and is located in the following path:

```
C:\Git\directory\texmf\tex\latex\folder
```

My MiKTeX configuration contains the previous path in its list of TEXMF root directories:

```
<path 1>
<path 2>
C:\Git\directory\texmf
<path 4>
...
```

Finally, the 2023 version is used as an input to file `bar.tex` located in `C:\Git\directory\subdirectory\subsubdirectory`. The specific code is:

```
\input{foo-2023.tex}
```

Now, the problem is as follows: I have just created a 2024 version by simply copy-pasting the 2023 version, and kept it in the same location as `foo-2023.tex`, however when I try to use the new version...

```
% \input{foo-2023.tex}
\input{foo-2024.tex}
```

... Latex is unable to find `foo-2024.tex` and throws.

I suspect the above is happening because Latex is searching somewhere else than `C:\Git\directory\texmf\tex\latex\folder` when I use command `\input{}` however I am unable to see any such configuration in the Latex file. I am also not sure how to investigate this; I have gone through the log but there are no indications near where the error is shown.

**Why is my new Latex file not being found, and how can I know in which location `\input{}` is searching for the file?**

Comment: I don't think this will answer your question, but a file like this should go in `texmf-local` (possibly `C:\Git\directory\texmf-local`).  That way, your next TeX update won't overwrite your personal file.

Comment: Seems **foo-2024.tex** is not in the same directory/folder as **bar.tex** but is in a directory/folder which is in the list of TEXMF root directories. So you may need to [refresh the file name database of MiKTeX](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/configuring.html).

Comment: @UlrichDiez much appreciate, that did solve the issue, I usually only refresh the FNDB when I modify the list of directories. Please feel free to turn your comment into an answer and I will mark it as answered.